# how to create border in html?

Tags: html, web

hi now i create one website in html but i have one doubt how to create border?
eg:

```
welcome to neevee
1. kkkkk
2. kliil
3. oomem
4. koemu
```

how to create this example content box or border box and border are same or different...help me....

Comment: You talk about `border` but you gave example of `list`. Both are very basic HTML/CSS you'll find them in any tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS) to style your pages to your liking, see the [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border) property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick tutorial to create border on your html element. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Answer (score 0):

To add a border to any kind of page element, you can use CSS.

```
<p style="border: 1px solid black;">
   Hello world!
</p>
```

In a `.css` file, you would say this:

```
p {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

This says to create a border that is 1 pixel wide, solid (rather than dashed or dotted, etc.), and black.

You can see more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

You should visit the links in the other answers so you can learn a bit more about HTML and CSS, as well.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that you can also further style the border and its corresponding content using more CSS or JavaScript. You can make a border fuzzy, give it a drop shadow, or make it rounded. Most of these functions are from CSS3, and you can check some of that out [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/).

Good luck!